# array_dif not working as the output is empty

Tags: php, arrays, array-difference

I created 2 arrays and want to check for the difference between both arrays (values). If I use my arrays with the function array_diff, the response is a empty Array, which is very wierd as I can't find the problem at all.

My setup:

```
// first array
$listing_products_sku = [
    '55995', '55996', '55999', '56000', '56005', '56006', '56007',
    '56008', '56021', '56022', '56023', '56024', '56029', '56030',
    '56031', '56032', '56036', '56037',
];

// second array:
$internal_products_sku = [
    '56015', '56016', '56014', '56018', '56019', '56020', '55994',
    '55995', '55996', '55997', '55998', '55999', '56000', '56001',
    '56002', '56003', '56005', '56004', '56006', '56007', '56008',
    '56009', '56010', '56011', '56012', '56013', '56017', '56021',
    '56022', '56023', '56024', '56025', '56026', '56027', '56028',
    '56029', '56030', '56031', '56032', '56033', '56034', '56035',
    '56036', '56037', '56038', '56039', '56040', '56041', '60434',
    '60435',
];

// used function:
$diff_result = array_diff($listing_products_sku, $internal_products_sku);
print_r($diff_result);
```

**Output**

```
Array ( )
```

**Help needed**

Is anybody able to explain why this happens and how I can make this working?

Comment: Please, include the **actual array definition** within the question, not noly `var_dump`output.

Comment: `array_diff()` *returns the values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays*, not just the difference between the arrays, you may want to swap the order you pass the arrays.

Comment: Your first array has 18 elements and your second array 50. I wont check each of the elements, but are you sure array1 has any element that's **not present on array2**?

Comment: @yivi I first created 2 arrays: `$listing_products_sku = array();
$internal_products_sku = array();` - After that I use array_push(); to add elements in it with another function which is working perfectly as the output of the Arrays is correct.

Comment: @NigelRen If I swap those variable, then the output is the same Array list with 50 items as `$internal_products_sku`

Comment: @yivi You are correct. First array elements are all present on Array2. I want an output with the difference between the 2 arrays, which should in this case 32 items which are different and are no match.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/Do9Sg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_diff()` returns array from first array containing values not exist in rest of the arrays (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php). As your first array's element are already exist in second array (`$internal_products_sku`) this is why its returning empty array.

So to find the difference all you have to do is take the `$internal_products_sku` array as first param then check

```
$diff_result = array_diff($internal_products_sku, $listing_products_sku);
print_r($diff_result);
```

Now it will return an array with those value not exist in `$listing_products_sku`

Comment: You are fully correct. It is my mistake. The output its given looks like the same amount as the key ends on 49. But if I calculate them, they are 32 items. This works, thanks!

Comment: Yep, look here for the array_diff with different argument orders with your data: https://3v4l.org/MaGdY